# AWS Access Key error when uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket but am receiving the following error:

```
Error message The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
http sttus code 403
awsError code InvalidAccessKeyId
Error type Client
request id EBE24FB4C8A92069
reject by AmazonServiceExceptions
Error message The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
http sttus code 403
awsError code InvalidAccessKeyId
Error type Client
request id 64332CFB941E77EC
Download FIle
reject by reason
Error message The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
http sttus code 403
awsError code InvalidAccessKeyId
Error type Client
request id ACA453705B9C4813
```

Comment: Error message is clear - you are using an access key which has not been provisioned in IAM in the account you are attempting to access.

Comment: selfexplined output

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

API calls to AWS require credentials to validate your identity. This is normally an **Access Key** and a **Secret Key**. The error is indicating that you have an invalid Access Key.

You can obtain the Access Key for your User from the IAM Console.

See: [Understanding and Getting Your Security Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#iam-user-name-and-password)

Comment: i did the same ..from security credentials i use the access key and secret key still same error

Comment: Where did you get the Access Key? Does it start with `AKIA...`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm getting the same error. I obtained the keys from the Users from IAM. I have enabled full S3 access. My Access Key start with AKIA. I have copied the key and am using it `AwsSessionCredentials` which is then passed to an `S3AsyncClient`.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.